# Como faço para conectar um programa em java com oracle 10g?

Tags: java, oracle10g, conexão

Já tentei fazer o código abaixo mas não deu certo, estou usando Oracle 10g.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class AcessoBanco {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        String sql = "select id_usuario, nome_razao from usuario";
        String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe";

        try(
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "david", "5550123");
        PreparedStatement stm = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery()){
            while(rs.next()){
                System.out.println(rs.getString("nome_razao"));
            }
        }
//      rs.close();
//      stm.close();
//      con.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: descreve o que exatamente você quer dizer com `não deu certo`

Answer (score 1):

Você deve fazer o download do driver JDBC no seguinte link: [Oracle Database 10g Release 2 JDBC Drivers](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-10201-088211.html).

Inclua o jar baixado ao Build Path do seu projeto.

Faça seu código carregar dinamicamente a classe `oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver` antes de chamar o método getConnection(), assim:

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
```

Se código vai ficar assim:

```
try(Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"); //repare nessa linha
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "david", "5550123");
        PreparedStatement stm = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery()){
    while(rs.next()){
        System.out.println(rs.getString("nome_razao"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Mas eu já estou na classe principal, deu erro.

Comment: @user4873 veja o meu try como ficou